# Precalculus ( Function):Find the range of $f(x) =\frac{1}{2\cos x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the range of $f(x) =\frac{1}{2\cos x-1}$

We know that $ -1 \leq cos x \leq 1$

= $-2 \leq 2\cos x \leq 2$

= $ -3 \leq 2\cos x -1 \leq 1$

Now how to proceed to get the range of the given function which is $\frac{1}{2\cos x-1}$

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Subdivide in two:

$$\color{red}{-3\le2\cos x-1\le 0}: \iff -\frac1{3}\le\frac1{2\cos x-1}\le 0$$

(Observe that the two succesive divisions flip over the inequality sign *twice* and thus things remain as they were)

$$\color{green}{0\le2\cos x-1\le 1}: \iff 1\le\frac1{2\cos x-1}\;\;\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: please set $\cos x=\frac12$

Comment: Please let the OP figure out some stuff, @labbhattacharjee ...

Comment: I left the OP to find put that the two conditions can not occur together:)

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle  -3\le y\le 1,$

If $\displaystyle  y\ge0,$ we have $\displaystyle y\le1\iff \frac1y\ge1$

If $\displaystyle y<0,$ we have $\displaystyle y\ge-3,\frac1y \le-\frac13$

The last part will be more clear if we set $y=-z$

As $\displaystyle-3\le y<0,-3\le-z<0\iff 3\ge z>0\iff\frac13\le \frac1z<\infty$

$\displaystyle\implies \frac13\le -\frac1y\iff -\frac13\ge \frac1y$

Comment: Paraphrasing you, "please set $\;y=0\;$ ..."

Comment: @DonAntonio, $y=0\implies \frac1y\to\infty$ which is definitely  $\ge1$. Observe that the two conditions are mutually exclusive

Comment: No kidding, @lab ! :)

Answer (score 0):

We know that `range of f(x)=domain of f^(-1)(x)`

Given $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2cosx−1}$$

**Finding inverse of f(x)**
$$y=\frac{1}{2cosx−1}$$
Replace **x** and **y** and
represent y as function of x
$$x=\frac{1}{2cosy−1}$$
$$2cosy-1=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$cos(y)=(\frac{1}{x}+1)\frac{1}{2}$$
$$y=cos^-1(\frac{1+x}{2x})$$

we know that **domain of cos^-1(x)** is
$$-1 ≤ x ≤1$$

now, $$-1≤\frac{1+x}{2x}≤1$$
$$-2x≤1+x≤2x$$
$$-3x≤1\& 1≤x$$
$$x≤\frac{-1}{3}\&x≥1$$

So, **Domain of f^-1(x)**=$$x ≤ -1/3  ⋃ x ≥ 1$$

So answer of question, **Range of f(x)** = Domain of f^-1(x)=$$x ≤ -1/3  ⋃ x ≥ 1$$

Also, the way you tried was too hasty you need to put domain after you take out inverse.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).